# Vue-Routes redirect doesn't work and beforeEnter render App component again

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm getting some issues when trying to redirect to an external link.

for ex:

```
{ path: '*', redirect: 'https://google.com'}
```

when I use "redirect" it doesn't work completely, but when I use something like that

```
{ path: '/*',
  beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
    window.location = "https://google.com"
  }
 }
```

it works but there is a problem because first, it tries to render App component again but there is no component so  be empty and a blank page is being rendered for nearly 1-1.5 second then it redirects to target URL and I don't want it to reload App component, just redirect it to other link. I googled but found nothing noteworthy.

Or maybe is there another way like deactive a component or use v-if or directly rendering a html file?

Answer (score 1):

`redirect` is meant to redirect to another route defined by your application, not to go to another website directly.

`window.location` works, but I think the behavior is somewhat browser-dependent.

Comment: And is there no other solution?

Comment: Maybe use window.location directly where you want it instead of invoking a route?